# Will stacking 2 junction boxes make inspector Happy?

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box

I had to relocate a 2 switch box to a new wall ( new location). I didn't notice that insulation of two existing cables are damaged. Damn!

so I put a electric tape around the cable in damaged area. But after went through some posts, inspector may not going to like this. Also it depends upon inspector. Also another thing I noticed wires are shorter now for switch at new location.

I think junction box is good idea here, but I won't be able place a two gang box the old location  due to limited space. Here the old location doesn't mean exact location of switch. I meant was which side of wall it was placed initially.

Am I ending up here with stacking two single gang box at the old/existing location ?
Its not going look good after drywall.

Please help here.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Junction box does not need to be "right where the wire is damaged" - just needs to be somewhere that you can get undamaged wire into it, and then run undamaged (and long enough) wire (probably new) to the desired location.

Comment: Tape will never fly even 300v shrink tubing can be questionable depending on inspector. If you have attic access put your box up there with undamaged cables to your switch box location (any boxes have to be accessible).

Comment: Does the junction box needs to be a two gang box.

Comment: This is in basement. I don't think 2 gang box of 32 cu.in will be good fit to accommodate of total 14 conductors.

Comment: @vickyP Your photo is very grainy and could be improved also an idea of where and how far the wires go.  I count 7 current carrying conductors assuming that is indeed the red of a 3 wire cable.  A better picture and better description, including what devices will be in the box and your location will allow people to tell you how big of a box you need.  Another option is to use separate single gang boxes, although that gives you less ability to switch things around in the future.